# particles from waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If you slide a styrofoam cup containing milky coffee accross a formica tabletop, the friction of the styrofoam on the formica, will produce a wave

interference pattern on the surface of the coffee.

This produces bumps and troughs on the surface. However, if you get the speed of the coffeecup just right, you get little coffee balls - perfect

spheres - rolling around on the surface !

The question is: are these actually spheres held in their shape by surface tension... or are they just the  appearance of spheres caused by a

moving intereference pattern of one continuous surface.

It certainly looks like the former.

One way to decide the issue would be to inject a thin stream of blue ink accross the diameter of the surface. If the balls were just a moving

interference 'bump', they would be blue while crossing the blue line but would revert to cream-coloured after having crossed the blue line of ink.

If on the other hand, they were separate spheres, they would pick up some of the blue ink on crossing the blue line and remain tinted blue after

having crossed it.

It is an interesting demonstration of how wave interference can apparently produce particle-like structures.

Now imagine a big ball of coffee in gravity-free environment, with a gizmo at the center that can vibrate in the x, y and z directions independently,

producing a compression wave say, up towards the poles, from where concentric ripples travel out towards the equator and all over the surface

of the sphere, interfering and producing little coffee-balls hither and yon, that move all over the surface.

Now imagine the surface is a representation
of the space-time continuum. If particles are produced in a manner such as this, what relevance might this have to the computation of  the

allowed masses of the fundamental particles from pure geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're engaging in an interesting philosophy.  QM has been modeled by a set of equations.  You have found a physical analogy, stretched it really far, and then tried to see if it still fits the original physics.

The closest I have seen to your thinking is Faraday waves, which deal with the movement of particles on a wavelike surface.  There is a direct connection between that and deBroglie-Bohem interpretation of QM.

Comment: My pet theory is that the coffee got cold (that's why he wasn't drinking it).